# PHP mysql database mistakes

Tags: php, mysql

Lines 18 22 28 33 have errors cant seem find them.

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
require_once('adam_error_handler.php');

class Chat
{
    private $mysqli;
    //constructor open database
    function __construct(){
        $this->mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

        //destructor closes database connection
        function __destruct(){
            $this->mysqli->close();
        }

        //truncate (empties) the table cotaining all messages
        public function deleteAllMessages(){
            $query='TRUNCATE TABLE chat';
            $result= $this->mysqli->query($query);
        }
        public function postNewMessage(){$user_name,$message,$color){

            $user_name=$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($user_name);
            $message=$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($message);
            $color=$this->mysqli->real_escape_string($color);
            $query='INSERT INTO chat (post_on, user_name, message, color)'
                'VALUES (
                        NOW(),
                        "'.$user_name.'",
                                        "'.$message.'",
                                                        "'.$color.'");
                                                        $result=$this->mysqli->query($query);                
                 }

 }
?>
```

Comment: There are no line numbers -- which are the ones with errors. What are the error messages?

Comment: `public function postNewMessage(){$params){` what kind of syntax is this?

Comment: Everywhere where i have public function theirs error on that line im using dreamweaver doesnt give me type error.Also error where it says VALUES

Answer (score 0):

Here are the syntax errors I can see:

- You forgot to end the `__construct` method. As a result, all the other functions are being defined internally to the constructor. But you're not allowed to define methods within methods. It should be:

  ```
  function __construct(){
      $this->mysqli= new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
  }
  ```
- You have a syntax error when defining `postNewMessage`. The parameter variables should be inside parentheses, by you have some extra braces. It should be:

  ```
  public function postNewMessage($user_name,$message,$color){
  ```
- When assigning to `$query`, you're missing a concatenation operator (`.`) between the string starting with `INSERT` and the string starting with `VALUES`. The first line should be:

  ```
  $query='INSERT INTO chat (post_on, user_name, message, color)'.
  ```

Comment: @AdamVazquez That's an error being fired because you are defining a function within a function I presume

Comment: @AdamVazquez With a `}` just like any other method.